# Prolog answers Argument = Argument, instead of answer No

Tags: list, prolog, arguments, undefined

How can I make prolog answer No , if search_answer didn't find an answer , and 
Yes with L = [*Answer*]

search_answer : predicate that returns a list or let's A as a free variable.

```
 found_list(L) :-
   search_answer(L).
```

For example , when asked `found_list(L)` , although search_answer didn't find an answer , Prolog still answers Yes. I print `L` , and it is equal to `_496` , a free variable.

Given the above piece of code, `found_list` answers `L = [...]` if `search_answer` found a list , else returns `L = L`, while I want to answer no

I tried the following , but doesn't work

```
found_list(L) :-
   search_answer(L) , is_list(L).
```

---

[image]

`liar_detector` is my `search_answer` predicate , with `L = answer`
and liars is my `found_answer`

Comment: There's no way that `found_list(L) :-
   search_answer(A).` will result in `L = [...]` under any circumstances since your predicate doesn't instantiate `L`. It will only succeed or fail and warn you that `A` and `L` are singleton. I think that's not what you ran.

Comment: my typo , I meant L , i will correct it

Comment: It's generally not considered good practice here to post code and result image snapshots. it's best to edit your question and enter new code as text and results as text unless you're trying to show a graphical result.

Comment: I took another stab at what your requirements are, so see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In `found_list(L) :- search_answer(A).` both `L` and `A` are singleton. I assume you saw the warning. You need to fix that for this predicate to make sense. Do you really want `L = [Answer]` or `L = Answer`?

You can achieve what you're after this way:

```
found_list(A) :-
    search_answer(A).
```

This will fail (result in "no") if `search_answer(A)` doesn't succeed, and your result will be `A` if it does succeed.

If you want the result as an answer within a list, you can do this:

```
found_list([A]) :-
    search_answer(A).
```

I'm not sure what the value is of either of these. The first `found_list/1` is just a simple wrapper on `search_answer/1` without any additional logic. The second simply makes a single-element list out of the `search_answer/1` result. If `A` is already a list, you don't need to put it inside of brackets (`[...]`), otherwise you just get a list within a list. I suspect you are really trying to do something else but haven't explained.

---

In response to the updated question, the following code should work if `A` is a simple unbound term:

```
found_list(A) :-
    search_answer(A),
    is_list(A).
```

However, `is_list/1` will succeed if its argument has a list structure even though it's elements may be unbound:

```
| ?- X = [_], is_list(X).

X = [_]

yes
| ?-
```

So, for example, if `search_answer(A)` succeeds with `A = [_]`, then `found_list(A)` will suceed with `A = [_]`.

`ground/1` can be useful here since:

```
| ?- ground(X).

no
| ?- ground([_|_]).

no
| ?- ground([a,b]).

yes
| ?-
```

Thus, the following solution should work:

```
found_list(A) :-
    search_answer(A),
    ground(A).
```

---

If your intention is not to backtrack to `search_answer(A)` if `A` is not ground, but just fail, you could implement `found_list/1` as:

```
found_list(A) :-
    search_answer(A),
    ( ground(A) -> true ; !, false ).
```

I think, though, there may be a more fundamental issue with the code, as it shouldn't have a behavior that you feel compelled to work around like this.

Comment: L = answer is what I want. I will update with an example

Comment: @HakiTerror the code image you showed isn't clear to me. You're having some kind of problem with your code, but your simplified example doesn't describe it properly. Please explain clearly what you want your actual predicate to do.